# Memory used in Azure Analysis Services

Tags: azure, memory, cube, azure-analysis-services

I was wondering, I have two cubes on my Azure Analysis Services with an estimated size of 4.8gb and 500mb (estimated in SSMS). So approximately 5.3gb on my server. But when I go to the metrics in Azure Analysis Services, and click on Memory, I see 9.8gb used. There is so a real gap between those two values.

Any idea how the "missing" 4.5gb are used ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you pause your Azure Analysis Services server and the resume it and connect a MDX query window to both databases in SSMS, then what does the memory usage say? There are a number of caches that get filled as users query the model. This should exclude those caches.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see this change while refreshing data on cubes?
If yes, then it is usual behaviour of Azure Analysis services where while refreshing the cubes, 2.5 times is the total memory in use approximately until the complete cube is refreshed.

The reason we got from experts is old data is still present in memory until the new one is not fully processed and stored.